# PHP strpos(), echoing instances found

Tags: php, echo, strpos

Using the `strpos()` function in PHP, how can I echo what `strpos()` has found? All items that it has found. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you do understand what this function does?

Comment: Yes, finds specified text from a string. I want it to echo what it finds.

Comment: Agreed with Col. Shrapnel - You're probably more interested in looking for preg_match or some other regular expression function

Comment: `preg_match` looks better. thanks

Answer (score 0):

[strpos](http://php.net/strpos) finds is what you tell it to find, so in essense you're asking this:

```
$needle="foo";
if (strpos($haystack, $needle)!==false)
{
    echo $needle;
}
```

Maybe you actually want to do something else?

Comment: If it does find it, it returns the position its at in the string using 0 based values. So if you asked to find "foo" in "foobar" it will return 0.

Answer (score 0):

strpos() only returns the first needle found in the haystack. If you need to find all of them, you can do something like this :

```
$str = "abcabcabc";
$arr = array();
$delChar = 0;

while (($pos = strpos($str, "a")) !== false) {
    $arr[] = $pos + $delChar;
    $delChar += strlen($str) - strlen(substr($str, $pos + 1));
    $str = substr($str, $pos + 1);
}

var_dump($arr);
```

which prints 0, 3 and 6.

Edit: I just read the comments, I assumed you meant the positions the function found, maybe I was wrong :-p